# Reduce silver oxide battery 1.5v to 1.3v

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I am looking to reduce the voltage of a silver oxide battery from 1.5 to 1.3 volt for a Bulova Accutron movement. The watch movement uses approx 4.5 to 7 micro amperes. I have used the formula for trying a resistor but cannot find a resistor that would work. I hope you guys on here can help me.

Dan the Horologist

Comment: In all probability,the watch will work fine with the slightly higher voltage.  Have you tried it? In any case, a 40k resistor will drop 0.2 volts at 5 microamperes.

Answer (score 4):

My [vintage Spaceview](http://www.mybob.net/spaceview_69/spaceview1.jpg) runs fine directly on the silver oxide battery, but I know that not all do.

[image]

I think a small Schottky diode could be added internally so that non-mercury batteries could be used thenceforth. Given the costs for servicing these finicky watches, you could probably charge $100 or more to add a 10-cent diode such as [this one](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/BAT54WX(SOD-523).PDF).

[image]

There are even smaller diodes that might work too, but if you stick to a fairly low voltage rating and a fairly high current rating the voltage drop should be around 200mV at low current.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Schottky diode. Schottky diodes have a low forward voltage drop, typically 0.25 to 0.4 volts.

Comment: This is great information. There are some people making a modified battery, they may be using something like this. I will give it a try. Most Accutrons do run at 1.5 but the are a few that run too fast that indexing and phasing can't correct.